# Помогите с мобильным меню

Tags: javascript, меню

возникла проблема с мобильным меню. При переходе на разные страницы сайта с ним проблем нет, но когда пытаешься перейти на якорь одной страницы меню переходит, но при этом не исчезает, и непонятно ты перешел по ссылке или нет. Поискал в интернете, но толкового решения не нашел, или же моих скудных познаний в JS не хватило их понять. Однако нашел вот такой кусок кода:

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != 'test' && e.target.id != 'menu') {
    $("#menu").hide();
  } else if (e.target.id != 'menu') {
    $("#menu").toggle();
  }
});
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопку меню открывает нужную часть сайта и исчезает, но возникла другая проблема, повторно меню открыть невозможно. Оно вроде как открываеться, но его не видно. При перезагрузке страницы так же...один раз открывается и все... Помогите решить проблему)

```html
<nav class="xs-menus">
   <div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-toggle" id="test"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="nav-menus-wrapper" id="menu">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
                   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Получается что есть меню и есть кнопка которая его открывает или скрывает + меню должно скрываться при нажатии на элемент меню?

Comment: Именно, часть ссылок в меню ведут на другие страницы, но есть пара страниц где контент открывается в ней же, при нажатии на линки информация подтягивается, но из-за меню её не видно ((